# CSS 'text-overflow:ellipsis' doesn't work properly on the 2nd line in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a limited area (`width: 200px`) for displaying a full name. I have to follow such html-construction (two SPANs inside DIV):

```css
.fullName {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullName">
  <span class="firstName">
    AlbertAlbertAlbertAlbertAlbertAlbertAlbertAlbert
  </span>
  <span class="lastName">
    EinsteinEinsteinEinsteinEinsteinEinsteinEinstein
  </span>
</div>
```

Expected behavior:

1. first and last names aren't too long - should be displayed in one line.
2. first and last names are long enough (but less than 200 px for each) - should be displayed in two lines
3. one of tne names takes less than 200px, other one takes more than 200px - should be displayed in two lines with `...`-sign in the end of the line with the longest name
4. both names take more than 200px each - should be displayed in two lines with `...`-signs in the end of the lines

As you can see the code above meets all the expectations in Chrome and Firefox. However it doesn't work properly in IE - it just trims the 2nd line without adding a `...`-sign.

Pure CSS solution preferred. I have a JS-solution but my team insist on pure CSS solution for suck little issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to work the element shall establish a box - to be either `display:block` or `display:inline-block`, try this one:

And the `<span>` has `display:inline` by default.

```css
.fullName {border: 1px solid blue; width:50%}

.fullName > span {
  max-width:100%;
  border: 1px solid red; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullName">
  <span class="firstName">
    AlbertAlbertAlbertAlbertAlbertAlbertAlbertAlbert
  </span>
  <span class="lastName">
    EinsteinEinsteinEinsteinEinsteinEinsteinEinstein
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: with `display: block` for SPANs it doesn't meet the expectation #1 - first and last **names aren't too long** - should be displayed **in one line**

Comment: with `display: inline-block` it doesn't meet all the other expectation because SPANs will be always inline

Comment: `text-overflow: ellipsis;` is always about single line of text.

Comment: Yes, it is. So am I able to aply `text-overflow: ellipsis` properly to both `<span>` according to all my success criteria?

Comment: text-overflow works when following conditions are met: 1) the element establishes box, 2) it is a single line of text (e.g. `white-space:nowrap` ) 3) width of text exceeds width of box it is rendered in and 4) `text-overflow: ellipsis` is defined on it.

Comment: Yes, I see. Does it mean that my problem doesn't imply pure-css solution?

Comment: Check my updated sample ( click on Run code snippet -> Full screen -> resize the window ). Is this close to what you want?